# VB.NET Updating Access is not updating all fields

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am currently have an issue with update command (OleDb). The description, type, and assemble fields are updating; however, the Part Number is not. Part number is not a primary key. My code is below.

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Office\Documents\SORINEX.accdb")
    Dim DataInsert As String = "UPDATE Product SET [Product Type] = @ProductType, [Description] = @Description, [Assembly] = @Assy_Yes WHERE [Part Number] = @PartNumber"
    con.Open()

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(DataInsert, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductType", Part_Type.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Part_Description.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assy_Yes", Assy_Yes)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", Part_Number.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Part Updated.")
    End Using

    con.Close()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your SQL is just using the PartNumber as part of the WHERE clause; there is no `SET` for it (all of which can be omitted using `UPDATE tbl (colA, ColB...) VALUES (valA, valB...) WHERE colX = @valX`)

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of an example of using this syntax.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm

Comment: What is the logic? What are you trying to do? Why update the very field you condition on?

Comment: @Brad its doing exactly what you are asking it to. If you want your part number to update you cant add it to the `where` clause. Everything you want to update is in the format of `SET field = @variable` and then the where clause just tells you what rows to set (how can you determine what row needs to be updated)

Comment: You already have an example. Your code is the example. You're already setting three columns because you specify those columns in the `SET` clause. If you want to set another column, include it in the `SET` clause too.  Of course, if you want to identify a record by a column and set that column too then you'll need two parameters: one for the current value and one for the new value. That's not something that you would generally want to do though.

Comment: I just realised that @Plutonix's first reply mixed up the syntax of an `UPDATE` and an `INSERT`.  You're doing the `UPDATE` the right way but you're just not including the `PartNumber` column in the `SET` clause so it won't be set.

Comment: Thank you! I have it working now.